# More specific antonym to "lodger" than "landlord"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

You can distinguish between someone who's paying for a room and paying for an apartment or house with [lodger](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lodger) versus [tenant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenant#Noun).

Is it possible to distinguish between someone who offers a room for rent and offers an apartment or house for rent? Are there any hyponyms for "landlord" that make this distinction?

I checked onelook.com's reverse dictionary, and the thesauri recommended on meta, and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well *tenant* is the antonym of *landlord*.

From Oxford English Dictionary (OED):

> landlord, n.
>
> Originally, a lord or owner of land; in recorded use applied only spec. to the person who lets land to a tenant.
>
> tenant, n
>
> One who holds a piece of land, a house, etc., by lease for a term of years or a set time. (The ordinary current sense. Correlative to landlord.)

*Lodger* would also strangely be the closest antonym for *lodger*.

From OED:

> lodger, n.
>
> One who resides as an inmate in another person's house, paying a certain sum periodically for the accommodation.
>
> One who lodges a person; a host. Obs.

*Renter* may also apply, depending on how the word is used:

> renter, n
>
> A person who collects rents (esp. those belonging to a corporate body), taxes, or tribute.

Or *host*:

> host, n
>
> A man who lodges and entertains for payment; a man who keeps a public place of lodging or entertainment; the landlord of an inn.

Comment: Lodger-lodger weirdness is just odd. :D

Answer (score 3):

The word that comes to mind is *homeowner,* and [this source](http://articles.latimes.com/2011/dec/25/business/la-fi-rent-20111225) uses it in the context you mention.

Answer (score 2):

In this discussion of *boarding-house* on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boarding-House) (yes, a less-than-authoritative reference) the persons renting are referred to as *lodgers*.  The operator is referred to as *landlord*. The term *rooming house* also seems to be used interchangeably.

While I have never seen such usage, the terms *boarding-house keeper* or *boarding-house owner* (or *rooming house keeper or owner*) would seem appropriate. It should be noted that boarding-houses and rooming houses usually provided some meals, and that is not suggested in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

*Lessor* is the word for somebody who leases something, which is a more general and impersonal term than *landlord/-lady*.

Comment: I was after a more specific term, not a more general term.

Answer (score -1):

It seems, though, that the words "lodger" and "renter" might be used meaning the opposite things, depending on the conext, while the words "landlord/landlady or lesser" and "tenant" are far less ambiguous...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Dennis! I don't believe that you are answering the question at hand. I am actually a bit confused by what you are saying. The question is about how to specify whether a landlord is letting a room or a house/apartment. In a little while with some more 'reputation' you will be able to leave comments. This might better fit as a comment.